# imprimir elementos de una lista de 3 en 3... en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

quiero saber si hay otra forma de hacerlo y con menos código...
conforme le doy enter al input me imprime los elementos de la lista en forma horizontal en la consola. me funciona pero quedé con curiosidad

```
def Ver_libros(self):

    archivo1=open("archivo.txt", mode="r")
    lectura_archivo=archivo1.readlines()

    libros_cantidad=int(len(lectura_archivo)/3)

    print("veamos los {} libros que estan guardado...".format(libros_cantidad))
    time.sleep(1.5)
    os.system("cls")

    contador=0
    while contador<libros_cantidad: 

        for e in lectura_archivo[0:3]:
            print(e)

        input("")
        os.system("cls")
        del(lectura_archivo[0:3])   

        contador=contador+1

    input("no hay mas libros que visualizar...")

    archivo1.close()
    time.sleep(2.2)
    os.system("cls")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solución es válida, pero lo que menos me gusta de ella es que cuando terminas el bucle de imprimir, la lista `lectura_archivo` queda vacía, lo que te impedirá volver a iterar por ella para cualquier otra cosa. Sería mejor una solución que no "consuma" los elementos de la lista.

Por ejemplo, en lugar extraer la rodaja `[0:3]`, puedes extraer la rodaja `[contador*3:contador*3+3]`, de este modo no necesitas eliminar los tres que ya has mostrado.

Otro enfoque diferente consiste en escribir una pequeña función de ayuda, que llamaré `grouper()`, inspirada en la que se proporciona en [la documentación de `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), pero simplificada para este caso en que la lista siempre es múltiplo del tamaño del grupo:

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
    """Iterador que devuelve en cada iteración una tupla con n elementos
    que va extrayendo del iterable"""

    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)
```

Aunque esta función son solo dos líneas, éstas hacen uso de unos cuantos trucos avanzados y explicarlas convenientemente sería un poco largo (puedo hacerlo si estás interesado, dímelo en un comentario).

La usaríamos así por ejemplo. En el siguiente código, ya que no tengo tu archivo, directamente asignaré contenidos a la lista `lectura_archivo`. Además, en lugar de pausar y borrar la pantalla en cada iteración, separaré los "trios" por una línea con guiones, para poder mostrar aquí el resultado:

```
lectura_archivo = [
    "Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro", "Cinco", "Sais", "Siete", "Ocho", "Nueve",
    "Diez", "Once", "Doce", "Trece", "Catorce", "Quince"
]

for trio in grouper(lectura_archivo, 3):
  for linea in trio:
    print(linea)
  print("---")
```

Resultado:

```
Uno
Dos
Tres
---
Cuatro
Cinco
Sais
---
Siete
Ocho
Nueve
---
Diez
Once
Doce
---
Trece
Catorce
Quince
---
```

Comment: no entendí lo de la función pero la estructura del ultimo código me dio ideas, pero aún sigo creyendo que debe haber una forma más sencilla, no sé tal vez usando un range, creando un función que me ayude pero no siendo tan avanzado porque soy nivel junior claro...  tambien quiero saber como eliminar esos elementos de 3 en tres

Answer (score 0):

A partir de Python 3.12 existe en la biblioteca estándar [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched).

Puedes usarla simplemente:

```py
from itertools import batched

for libro_datos in batched(lectura_archivo, 3):
    for dato in libro_datos:
        print(dato)

    input("")
    os.system("cls")
```